# How to split an image by identifying single or multiple horizontal lines in Python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-segmentation

I want to split an image into multiple parts using Python based on the faint grey line between questions.(as in image below).  Is there a way to do so?
[image: Image to split]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a **mask** of the horizontal lines, then use `cv2.reduce` to **reduce** the image to a **column** using the `MAX` value. By detecting contours you can calculate the starting *vertical* coordinate of the lines in the reduced mask and finally, `crop` the image using this info. Something like this:

```
# Set image path
imagePath = "D://opencvImages//"
imageName = "zlSGu.jpg"

# Read image:
inputImage = cv2.imread(imagePath + imageName)
# Store a copy for results:
inputCopy = inputImage.copy()

# Convert BGR to grayscale:
grayInput = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Set a lower and upper range for the threshold:
lowerThresh = 230
upperThresh = 235

# Get the lines mask:
mask = cv2.inRange(grayInput, lowerThresh, upperThresh)
```

This gives you the lines mask:

[image]

Which is a little bit noisy, your image is compressed. Let's apply an `areaFilter` with a minimum area of 50 to filter out this noise:

```
# Set a filter area on the mask:
minArea = 50
mask = areaFilter(minArea, mask)
```

This is the mask filtered:

[image]

Now, reduce the image to a column using the `MAX (255)` intensity value:

```
# Reduce matrix to a n row x 1 columns matrix:
reducedImage = cv2.reduce(mask, 1, cv2.REDUCE_MAX)
```

This is the reduced image, which is a little bit hard to see here, but only the gray lines (reduced to a column) are shown. Now, let's detect the starting and ending points of these lines - which are really just a vertical coordinate. We can calculate this coordinate from the line's bounding box:

```
# Find the big contours/blobs on the filtered image:
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Store the lines here:
separatingLines = []

# We need some dimensions of the original image:
imageHeight = inputCopy.shape[0]
imageWidth = inputCopy.shape[1]

# Look for the outer bounding boxes:
for _, c in enumerate(contours):

    # Approximate the contour to a polygon:
    contoursPoly = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 3, True)

    # Convert the polygon to a bounding rectangle:
    boundRect = cv2.boundingRect(contoursPoly)

    # Get the bounding rect's data:
    [x, y, w, h] = boundRect

    # Start point and end point:
    lineCenter = y + (0.5 * h)
    startPoint = (0,int(lineCenter))
    endPoint = (int(imageWidth), int(lineCenter))

    # Store the end point in list:
    separatingLines.append( endPoint )

    # Draw the line using the start and end points:
    color = (0, 255, 0)
    cv2.line(inputCopy, startPoint, endPoint, color, 2)

    # Show the image:
    cv2.imshow("inputCopy", inputCopy)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I've additionally stored the line's data in the `separatingLines` list. Also, just for displaying purposes, I've drawn the lines on the original input. This is the image of the identified lines:

[image]

Now, these lines are unsorted. Let's `sort` them based on their vertical coordinate. After the lines are correctly sorted, we can `crop` each section as we loop through the lines list. Like this:

```
# Sort the list based on ascending Y values:
separatingLines = sorted(separatingLines, key=lambda x: x[1])

# The past processed vertical coordinate:
pastY = 0

# Crop the sections:
for i in range(len(separatingLines)):

    # Get the current line width and starting y:
    (sectionWidth, sectionHeight) = separatingLines[i]

    # Set the ROI:
    x = 0
    y = pastY
    cropWidth = sectionWidth
    cropHeight = sectionHeight - y

    # Crop the ROI:
    currentCrop = inputImage[y:y + cropHeight, x:x + cropWidth]
    cv2.imshow("Current Crop", currentCrop)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    # Set the next starting vertical coordinate:
    pastY = sectionHeight
```

And these are the cropped portions of the image. Note that these are individual images:

[image]
[image]
[image]

This is the definition and implementation of the `areaFilter` function:

```
def areaFilter(minArea, inputImage):
    # Perform an area filter on the binary blobs:
    componentsNumber, labeledImage, componentStats, componentCentroids = \
    cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(inputImage, connectivity=4)

    # Get the indices/labels of the remaining components based on the area stat
    # (skip the background component at index 0)
    remainingComponentLabels = [i for i in range(1, componentsNumber) if componentStats[i][4] >= minArea]

    # Filter the labeled pixels based on the remaining labels,
    # assign pixel intensity to 255 (uint8) for the remaining pixels
    filteredImage = np.where(np.isin(labeledImage, remainingComponentLabels) == True, 255, 0).astype('uint8')

    return filteredImage
```