# im looking for a something that can crop and save parts of an image based on its contents

Tags: python, image-processing, crop

For example:

[image]

it will look at the question numbers 1 and 2 and crop everything between those two and save the cropped part as another jpg file, same with all the other questions

Comment: The question as it is might have infinite solutions depending on what are your constraints. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Nikan see this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66938132).

Comment: @Bilal thanks! ill check it out

Comment: @HirabayashiTaro im not sure i quite get what you mean, may i know what you need me to be specific about!

Comment: @Nikan Sure. For example if all your questions are in the exact same position relative to the image you might just crop by the known position. If they are not you need to find a way around it, and depending on your input there might be many different ones.