How can I segment the handwritten lines in this type of documents?
This is the document page. I want to segment the 10 handwritten lines perfectly and then crop it to save it to train my model.
What methods can I use??
I don't want to make my own model to segment those lines. I am looking a another straightforward method.

Here the code and more image samples:
https://github.com/MuhammadSabah/SO-Attempt

You have nice, perfectly horizontal rule lines that separate your lines. If you take the horizontal projection of the image, the minimums should be those rule lines. (See reduce() and REDUCE_SUM.)

Another way is to threshold, then invert so the text is white on black. Then you can use a long horizontal morphology kernel with small height to combine all the text in each line. Then get the contours. Then crop the input using the bounding boxes from the contours.

I am trying this, but it does not seem to work, could you please provide some code examples

The cropping part is what is challenging, I couldn't find a way to do it the way I wanted @fmw42

Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66938132/12728244 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/66500205/12728244

Show your code!  If you use my method above using morphology, you can easily get the bounding box information x,y,w,h and then use Numpy slicing crop = image[y:y+h, x:x+w] to crop each line of text.

Relevant:  https://ajlearn.net/opencv_textline_extraction_recognition,

I edited the question and added the code, could you please take a look at it.
@fmw42

Here is another attempt which I got closer to it, could you please check exp.py file, appreciate your help sir.
https://github.com/MuhammadSabah/SO-Attempt
@fmw42

You do not need that large a kernel.  It just needs to be large enough to connect characters in the row and not be so large that it will connect rows vertically. Try the maximum distance horizontally of the largest row or even perhaps half that. And less than half the distance vertically between your horizontal lines.  But the main issue is that you are trying to use contours before you have found them. Look into cv2.findContours(). I also suggest using cv2.imshow and cv2.imwrite rather than Mathplotpy for display and saving. That way you do not have to worry about the colormap.

Thanks for the notes, I fixed the kernel and the contours, but still the bounding boxes are not perfect, could you please check back the code and tell me how to improve it.
@fmw42

@Hama Sabah What do you think is wrong with the results? And what have you tried to correct it?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Have you tried the Hough transform for detecting lines?

Your main issue was your morphology kernel. It was not long enough nor tall enough to connect your characters. So here is a modified version that I used in Python/OpenCV. You also need to filter on the width and height of the bounding boxes. I also changed your code to use cv2 to show and save images.
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

image_path = 'page_2_gray.png'
print("Loading image from:", image_path)

if not os.path.isfile(image_path):
    print("Image file not found:", image_path)
else:
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    if image is None:
        print("Failed to load image.")
    else:
        print("Image loaded successfully:", image.shape)
        
        # get grayscale and binary image
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        _, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

        # apply morphology close
        kernel = np.ones((35,200), np.uint8)
        morph = cv2.morphologyEx(binary, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
        
        # show grayscale and binary image and morphology image      
        cv2.imshow('Grayscale Image', gray)     
        cv2.imshow('Binary Image', binary)
        cv2.imshow('Morphological Closed Image', morph)

        # get contours and sort them
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda c: cv2.boundingRect(c)[1])
        
        i = 1
        bboxes = image.copy()
        for c in contours:
            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
            if h > 75 and w > 800:
                # draw contour on input
                #cv2.drawContours(contour_img, [c], 0, (0,0,255), 1)
                
                # draw bounding boxes on input
                cv2.rectangle(bboxes, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 5)
                
                # crop image for given bounding box and save
                crop = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
                cv2.imwrite("page_2_gray_crop{0}.png".format(i),crop)
                i = i+1

        # show bounding boxes   
        cv2.imshow('Bounding Boxes', bboxes)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

        # save images       
        cv2.imwrite('page_2_gray_gray.png', gray)
        cv2.imwrite('page_2_gray_binary.png', binary)
        cv2.imwrite('page_2_gray_morph.png', morph)
        cv2.imwrite('page_2_gray_bboxes.png', bboxes)

        print("Number of contours detected:", len(contours))

Morphology Images:

Bounding Boxes on Input:

Unfortunately to catch your upper floated part of some character or accent(?), I had to increase the kernel height so much that the bounding boxes have the horizontal line included. You can reduce the height of the kernel so that the lines are not included, then then the floating part of the character is excluding.

the horizontal lines should respond well to a wide flat kernel

Yes, one could remove the horizontal lines from the input using morphology. I just did not go that far as he was asking me to comment on why his code did not work in the offline conversation above.

That works great for some of my documents, but there are some other cases where it does not work and the segmentation fails.
https://github.com/MuhammadSabah/SO-Attempt
I provided more sample images in this repository, where the segmentation sometimes crops half the page.
Is there any way to fix it and find an optimal solution
@fmw42

What do you think is wrong?  Look at your input image and the darkness of the text where the line of text are missing?  Those regions are too dark. Raise your threshold value above 15 (to around 240?) or some value that makes the thresholded text all dark, but not so much as to introduce dark noise pixels.  See my new script.  There is not going to be a method that is universal to every image. The font size will change and require you to adjust your morphology kernels, for example.  Your text darkness may change and you may need to adjust your threshold value. Etc.

Here is a revised version that filters out the long horizontal black lines before finding the lines of text.
It also crops out any black along the sides of the image.
Newer Input Image with the same Name:

import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

image_path = 'page_2_gray.png'
print("Loading image from:", image_path)

if not os.path.isfile(image_path):
    print("Image file not found:", image_path)
else:
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    hh, ww = image.shape[:2]
    
    if image is None:
        print("Failed to load image.")
    else:
        print("Image loaded successfully:", image.shape)
        
        # crop image on all sides to remove any dark at the very edge outside the margins
        amount = 10
        image = image[amount:hh-amount, amount:ww-amount]
        
        # pad back with white
        image = cv2.copyMakeBorder(image, amount, amount, amount, amount, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=(255,255,255))
        
        # get grayscale and binary image
        gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        _, binary1 = cv2.threshold(gray1, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

        # apply morphology close to find the horizontal lines
        kernel = np.ones((10,200), np.uint8)
        morph1 = cv2.morphologyEx(binary1, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

        # get contours for long horizontal lines
        contours1, _ = cv2.findContours(morph1, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        # remove horizontal lines
        i = 1
        image2 = image.copy()
        bboxes1 = image.copy()
        for c in contours1:
            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
            #print(x,y,w,">100",h,"<75")
            if h < 75 and w > 100:
                #print(x,y,w,h)
                                
                # cover image with white to remove horizontal lines and other short regions
                bias = 0
                image2[y-bias:y+h+bias, x:x+w] = (255,255,255)
                cv2.rectangle(bboxes1, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 5)
                i = i+1
            #print('')
        print("Number of long horizontal lines removed:", i-1)

        # get grayscale and binary image from horizontal lines removed image
        gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        _, binary2 = cv2.threshold(gray2, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

        # apply morphology close to find 
        kernel = np.ones((35,200), np.uint8)
        morph2 = cv2.morphologyEx(binary2, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
        
        # get contours and sort them
        contours2, _ = cv2.findContours(morph2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        contours2 = sorted(contours2, key=lambda c: cv2.boundingRect(c)[1])

        
        i = 1
        bboxes2 = image2.copy()
        for c in contours2:
            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
            if h > 75 and w > 800:
                
                # draw bounding boxes on input
                cv2.rectangle(bboxes2, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 5)
                
                # crop image for given bounding box and save
                crop = image2[y:y+h, x:x+w]
                cv2.imwrite("page_2_gray_crop{0}.png".format(i),crop)
                i = i+1
        print("Number of lines of text cropped:", i-1)

        # show bounding boxes   
        # show grayscale and binary image and morphology image      
        cv2.imshow('Grayscale Image1', gray1)       
        cv2.imshow('Binary Image1', binary1)
        cv2.imshow('Morphological Closed Image1', morph1 )
        cv2.imshow('Bounding Boxes1', bboxes1)
        
        cv2.imshow('Image2', image2)
        cv2.imshow('Grayscale Image2', gray2)       
        cv2.imshow('Binary Image2', binary2)
        cv2.imshow('Morphological Closed Image2', morph2 )
        cv2.imshow('Bounding Boxes2', bboxes2)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

        # save images       
        cv2.imwrite('page_2_gray_gray1.png', gray1)
        cv2.imwrite('page_2_gray_binary1.png', binary1)
        cv2.imwrite('page_2_gray_morph1.png', morph1)
        cv2.imwrite('page_2_gray_bboxes1.png', bboxes1)
        
        cv2.imwrite('page_2_gray_no_lines.png', image2)
        cv2.imwrite('page_2_gray_gray2.png', gray2)
        cv2.imwrite('page_2_gray_binary2.png', binary2)
        cv2.imwrite('page_2_gray_morph2.png', morph2)
        cv2.imwrite('page_2_gray_bboxes2.png', bboxes2)

Bounding Boxes of regions removed:

Lines removed Image:

Bounding boxes of lines of text:

Addition
This code should work better (find and remove the horizontal lines better and keep more of the text lines) if you increase your threshold value, i.e., replace:
_, binary1 = cv2.threshold(gray1, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
with
_, binary1 = cv2.threshold(gray1, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

This only became evident when looking at your other example images, which were not available originally.
I have added this change to the code.

That is amazing thanks, but I have some other sample images here
https://github.com/MuhammadSabah/SO-Attempt
where it fails at detecting some of the lines, could you please check it out

I answered that already below. Please look at your intermediate images to try to understand why the text is missing.  What is different about those text regions from the rest?

I think because the texts are lighter gray and was written using a lighter graphite pen, that is why it is harder to detect.

the contrast between the white background and the text is low, I will try to convert the image into black and white and see if it is still the case

Just raise the threshold value as I mentioned in my other comment in the post below.  Please read all comments.

I did, still the same issue

Use my code above and raise the threshold from 150 to 240 (i.e. 95% or nearly at the white level.  Does that now get your lighter text to threshold as black rather than merge with the white background?). Show your new code?

https://github.com/MuhammadSabah/SO-Attempt/tree/master/output-issues
Here are the issues, I used 150 for thresholding value, but even when I increase it, it is getting worse. I am using your exact code.

The code you show is not my revised code.  Use that with the threshold at 240

What is your version of Python and OpenCV?  Perhaps you are using a different version that I am (py312-opencv4 @4.9.0).  Do you not get the same result that I did for page_2_gray.png?

I used it locally, but the boxes are not even visible, you can try on the sample images I provided

My code works for page_2_gray.png. Does it not work for you?

Yes that is perfect, but the other samples are causing a lot of issues, where most of them are even the same as  page_2_gray.png, but idk why that happens

Your result for page_2_gray.png boxes shows that several of the bottom rows of text are all combined into one large box.  I have no idea why that is happening for you other than some code differences due to different versions. You have not answered my question about your version.  Alternately, the image I am using that you posted is different from the one you are using or the upload changed something. Please examine your image and the uploaded image.

Sorry, but just the image page_2_gray.png is different from output-issues/page_2_gray_bounding_boxes.png
I just uploaded some samples for you to see the problems that happens with other samples, but nonetheless your code works perfect with  page_2_gray.png as I run it locally.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
